# Casting List<T> to List<String> type

Tags: java, string, list, arraylist, casting

I am casting List <T> to List <String>. getClass() method on any element of list returns the actual class of element of List i.e  T rather than String. Shouldn't Java return String instead of actual class, as the list was casted to list of String?

```
public cast (List<?> unsortedList) {
    List<String> unsortedListOfPrimitives = (List<String>)unsortedList;
    System.out.println(unsortedListOfPrimitives.get(0).getClass());
}


cast(List<BigDecimal> unsortedList);

Output :  java.math.BigDecimal
```

Comment: Casting doesn't change an object in Java, unlike C++. You are just telling Java that the type T was "String." If you have `List<?> aList = new List<Integer>()` and later cast `List<String> sList=(List<String>) aList;`, `sList` is the same object, you've just got its type wrong.

Comment: It would help if you gave a specific example.

Comment: Thanks, Thomas. I have edited the question to include an example.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I convert from List<?> to List<T> in Java using generics?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3548733/how-do-i-convert-from-list-to-listt-in-java-using-generics)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java generics don't always work the way you'd expect.

Specifically, casting a generic to a specific type doesn't actually change the object, and you can get unsafe results when you do this and aren't 100% sure that you have it right.

So the object you have cast to `List<String>` is still actually a list containing `BigDecimal` entries, you have just mis-cast it.

This is a case where Java is type-unsafe - just as casting an `Object` to `Integer` is type-unsafe (but at runtime, unsafe `Object` to `Integer` casts will fail at the time of the cast, while generic casts will not fail until later.)

Comment: It's only unsafe if you ignore compile-time warnings.